# wrong Chile timezone in case of DST

Tags: php, timezone

I have a problem.. I am working on timezone on PHP but In case of chile I am facing problem. For chile CLT apply normally and CLST in case of Daylight saving and PHP code is America/Santiago. But it returns that currently there is no DST but actually currently there is DST.. Can anyone Help thanks,

Comment: Would you please show us your code.

Comment: <?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Santiago');echo "Current ".date('e T c I');?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
date_default_timezone_set ('America/Santiago');
$time = strtotime ('11 March 2011');

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i ++)
{
    echo "<br/>Current " . date ('e T c I', $time);
    $time += 60 * 60 * 24;
}
```

shows that

```
Current America/Santiago CLST 2011-03-11T00:00:00-03:00 1
Current America/Santiago CLST 2011-03-12T00:00:00-03:00 1
Current America/Santiago CLT 2011-03-12T23:00:00-04:00 0
Current America/Santiago CLT 2011-03-13T23:00:00-04:00 0
```

DST in your region ends by March, 12th.
Of course we both know that DST has been prolonged according to http://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/chile-longer-dst-2012.html, but PHP does not know that.

Comment: Thanks for commenting but this code is not returning right value . According to DST rule DST timing of there is : Start:October 11
End: March 29 so currently there should be DST on but not that case with this code

Comment: I am not the one to blame. It's the php function date(). Different PHP versions return different results.

Comment: I no php date function is returning wrong value. Thats why I am asking for solution because I do'nt want to do custom code in my project. Please Help!!

Comment: I'm afraid you're on your own on this one. I see two ways out: either you figure out all DST issues all by yourself, or you can resort to a paid service that allows you to know all the time stuff through their api.

Comment: We made our own database for all countries and managing that through php code all are returning right information except chile so we don't want to do custom code only for chile so we are searching any alternate solution for that. We want to know is there any way we can get right info of chile....

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. Updating the timezonedb works for me.

Go to: https://pecl.php.net/package/timezonedb

**For Widnows:**
Download the newest version of dll, copy into "ext" directory. Edit the php.ini and put below line:

extension=php_timezonedb.dll

**For Linux:** 
You can use :

pecl install timezonedb

and in php.ini put:

extension=php_timezonedb.so